# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am new to Android SDK/API environment. It's the first I am trying to draw a plot/chart. I tried running different kinds of sample codes on the emulator using 3 different free libraries, nothing is showing on the layout screen. The logcat is repeating the following message:

```
 W/Trace(1378): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 I/Choreographer(1378): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The problem didn't persist and the chart worked when I ran a sample code pertaining to an evaluation copy of a licensed library.

Comment: Are you drawing your charts on a separate thread?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited the question to make it more clear. The activity when running is showing that I am running an activity that have no design its layout => showing a white screen.

Comment: @Areks No, I am not using a separate thread.

Comment: I think you should, is not recommended at all to perform long operations on the main thread, because that freezes the entire application, you can read how to use threads here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391272/how-to-use-separate-thread-to-perform-http-requests

Ignore the "code to do the HTTP request" and just execute your potentially long operations there.

Comment: It seems a repeated question.
Please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858680/logcat-says-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread-and/)!
Thank you!

Comment: Why you don't try searching, you will find information about the choreographer. I recommend you to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat

Comment: I wiped emulator data, and everything returned to silky smooth. In my case, there was nothing heavy, all resources fine etc.

Comment: Depending on your app's functionality needs. This warning will be unavoidable in some cases. For example, my app uses a Geocoder to get the lat/lng of a user-inputed address. When a user types something vague like "Florida", I usually get this warning saying 35 frames were skipped. Sometimes it's not a big deal.

Comment: I got this error when I was assigning int value instead of String to textview.

Comment: I get this warning also when debuggin.. be sure you are not in debugg mode.

Comment: Did u find a solution am finding it hard evne to find what is cuasing the error

Answer (score 579):

taken from : **[Android UI : Fixing skipped frames](http://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/)**

> Anyone who begins developing android application sees this message on
>   logcat **“Choreographer(abc): Skipped xx frames! The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread.”** So what does it actually
>   means, why should you be concerned and how to solve it.

**What this means is that your code is taking long to process and frames
are being skipped because of it, It maybe because of some heavy
processing that you are doing at the heart of your application or DB
access or any other thing which causes the thread to stop for a while.**

> Here is a more detailed explanation:
>
> > Choreographer lets apps to connect themselves to the vsync, and
> >     properly time things to improve performance.
> >
> > Android view animations internally uses Choreographer for the same
> >     purpose: to properly time the animations and possibly improve
> >     performance.
> >
> > Since Choreographer is told about every vsync events, I can tell if
> >     one of the Runnables passed along by the Choreographer.post* apis
> >     doesnt finish in one frame’s time, causing frames to be skipped.
> >
> > In my understanding Choreographer can only detect the frame skipping.
> >     It has no way of telling why this happens.
> >
> > The message “The application may be doing too much work on its main
> >     thread.” could be misleading.
> >
> > source : 
> >     **[Meaning of Choreographer messages in Logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat)**
>
> **Why you should be concerned**
>
> When this message pops up on android
>   emulator and the number of frames skipped are fairly small (<100) then
>   you can take a safe bet of the emulator being slow – which happens
>   almost all the times. But if the number of frames skipped and large
>   and in the order of 300+ then there can be some serious trouble with
>   your code. Android devices come in a vast array of hardware unlike ios
>   and windows devices. The RAM and CPU varies and if you want a
>   reasonable performance and user experience on all the devices then you
>   need to fix this thing. When frames are skipped the UI is slow and
>   laggy, which is not a desirable user experience.
>
> **How to fix it**
>
> Fixing this requires identifying nodes where there is or
>   possibly can happen long duration of processing. The best way is to do
>   all the processing no matter how small or big in a thread separate
>   from main UI thread. So be it accessing data form SQLite Database or
>   doing some hardcore maths or simply sorting an array – Do it in a
>   different thread
>
> Now there is a catch here, You will create a new Thread for doing
>   these operations and when you run your application, it will crash
>   saying “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can
>   touch its views“. You need to know this fact that UI in android can be
>   changed by the main thread or the UI thread only. Any other thread
>   which attempts to do so, fails and crashes with this error. What you
>   need to do is create a new Runnable inside runOnUiThread and inside
>   this runnable you should do all the operations involving the UI. Find
>   an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254523/android-runonuithread-explanation).
>
> So we have Thread and Runnable for processing data out of main Thread,
>   what else? There is AsyncTask in android which enables doing long time
>   processes on the UI thread. This is the most useful when you
>   applications are data driven or web api driven or use complex UI’s
>   like those build using Canvas. The power of AsyncTask is that is
>   allows doing things in background and once you are done doing the
>   processing, you can simply do the required actions on UI without
>   causing any lagging effect. This is possible because the AsyncTask
>   derives itself from Activity’s UI thread – all the operations you do
>   on UI via AsyncTask are done is a different thread from the main UI
>   thread, No hindrance to user interaction.
>
> So this is what you need to know for making smooth android
>   applications and as far I know every beginner gets this message on his
>   console.

Comment: I just have an app where if I click a button, the background image of button changes and button is unclickable. How am I doing too much work :(

Comment: @Remian8985 - The background image change for the button (assuming that you are downloading this image) should be done in an AsyncTask - that is to perform that download background operation and publish the result on the UI thread (supply the image back). See Android Reference [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @BenJaminSila changing background in AsyncTask? Really?

Comment: @user25 *"assuming that you are downloading this image"*

Comment: "When this message pops up on android emulator and the number of frames skipped are fairly small (<100) then you can take a safe bet of the emulator being slow" Does this still apply today? Emulators are getting pretty fast right?

Comment: I have a question about "I can tell if one of the Runnables passed along by the Choreographer.post* apis doesnt finish in one frame’s time, causing frames to be skipped" . As we know the choreographer will process all the runnables whose dueTime is before now. Which means that it will do all the frames in later frame's time when one runnable takes long to execute. So no frame will be dropped, it just shows later.

Comment: AsyncTask is now deprecated!

Comment: It did worked for me, my lagging was for NotifyDataChange() and I did that call inside a RunOnUiThread which was also in another thread. it was necessary to run on UI thread to update data instantly in recycler view in UI.

Comment: @null_awe You should use either RxJava or even better, Coroutines, to perform long-running operations in a background thread.

Answer (score 302):

As others answered above, "Skipped 55 frames!" means some heavy processing is in your application.

For my case, there is no heavy process in my application. I double and triple checked everything and removed those process I think was a bit heavy.

I removed Fragments, Activities, Libraries until only the skeleton was left. But still the problem did not go away. I decided to check the resources and found some icons and background I use are pretty big as I forgot to check the size of those resources.

So, my suggestion is if none of the above answers help, you may also check your resource files size.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I had an application that was doing very little work but was slow and laggy. I kept getting skipped frames logs. Once I removed the background from my activity everything was fine. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, I believe this was exactly my problem. I tried a bunch of other (quite involved) solutions and the app was just as slow. I took out all web services, and tried to optimize my code down to the bone. Did not work, then I saw this. As soon as I removed my background image (largest image I have) the app works about as fast as you can click stuff, even with the old "slow" code.

Comment: @batsheva it is not necessary to be 1 KB. It depends on your needs, let's say you need clearer image, you may use higher resolution, but make sure you split into different sizes into the different folders of resources.

Comment: i have no image and all icons have small sizes but still take time could you give me another solution. If you have

Comment: this answer made my night... saved me for whole night after trying for almost 5 hours...

Comment: Worked great for me! and I also realized that I didn't detach *all* of my observers (especially those I have in my fragments)

Answer (score 75):

I too had the same problem.
Mine was a case where i was using a background image which was in drawables.That particular image was of approx 130kB and was used during splash screen and home page in my android app.

**Solution** - I just shifted that particular image to drawables-xxx folder from drawables and was able free a lot of memory occupied in background and the skipping frames were no longer skipping.

**Update** Use 'nodp' drawable resource folder for storing background drawables 
files.

[Will a density qualified drawable folder or drawable-nodpi take precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682094/will-a-density-qualified-drawable-folder-or-drawable-nodpi-take-precedence)

Comment: I moved my large background image from drawable to mimap-xxxhdpi and it did the trick!

Comment: This solution is doing the trick. I'm using folder `drawable-xxxhdpi` instead `drawable` what dramatically reduces the used memory (~70 percent less). Also good to know, screens with the same size vary in DPI size. The ratio in pixels between them is `ldpi = 1:0.75`, `mdpi = 1:1`, `hdpi = 1:1.5`, `xhdpi = 1:2`, `xxhdpi = 1:3`, `xxxhdpi = 1:4`. By using the the `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder you allow to downscale the images to your device's screensize what reduces memory and CPU consumption.

Comment: Moving images from `drawable` to `drawable-nodpi` prevents application from getting `Out of Memory Error`.

Comment: Oh my god... thanks! I had an image within the drawable folder and this made my app slow as hell (although the image was only 100kb!!!). After  generating the drawable-xxx files (I used the Android Drawable Importer) my app is damn fast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: but how to create drawable-xxx folder?

Answer (score 24):

Another common cause of delays on UI thread is SharedPreferences access. When you call a `PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences` and other similar methods for the first time, the associated .xml file is immediately loaded and parsed *in the same thread*.

One of good ways to combat this issue is triggering first SharedPreference load from the background thread, started as early as possible (e.g. from `onCreate` of your Application class). This way the preference object may be already constructed by the time you'd want to use it.

Unfortunately, sometimes reading a preference files is necessary during early phases of startup (e.g. in the initial Activity or even Application itself). In such cases it is still possible to avoid stalling UI by using `MessageQueue.IdleHandler`. Do everything else you need to perform on the main thread, then install the IdleHandler to execute code once your Activity have been fully drawn. In that Runnable you should be able to access SharedPreferences without delaying too many drawing operations and making Choreographer unhappy.

Comment: For this case, you should prefer apply() method instead of commit(). apply() method can not block UI.  You can look from here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: @EmreGürses your comment is exceptionally confusing - my answer isn't about writing to SharedPreferences, it is about *reading* them for the first time. Methods "apply" and "commit" has nothing to do with it at all.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. Android Emulator worked perfectly on Android < 6.0. When I used emulator Nexus 5 (Android 6.0), the app worked very slow with `I/Choreographer: Skipped frames` in the logs.

So, I solved this problem by changing in Manifest file `hardwareAccelerated` option to `true` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Update Jan 2022**. According to the comment from @M.Ed: Hardware acceleration is [enabled](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel) by default if you're targeting APIs >= 14.

Comment: For those reading this in the future, this is unnecessary. Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if you're targeting APIs above level 14. As per the documentation.
"Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14, but can also be explicitly enabled." Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel

Answer (score 18):

Try to use the following strategies in order to improve your app performance:

- Use multi-threading programming if possible. The performance benefits are huge, even if your smart phone has one core (threads can run in different cores, if the processor has two or more). It's useful to make your app logic separated from the UI. Use Java threads, AsyncTask or IntentService. [Check this](https://developer.qualcomm.com/blog/multi-threading-android-apps-multi-core-processors-part-1-2).
- Read and follow the misc performance tips of Android development website. [Check here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html).

Comment: your first link requires that you "...have a validated account..." to access it.

Answer (score 9):

Optimize your images ... Dont use images larger than 100KB ... Image loading takes too much CPU and cause your app hangs .

Comment: Decrease size of image either by java code or use photoshop to crop images.. also compress images using compressor.io

Answer (score 8):

I am not an expert, but I got this debug message when I wanted to send data from my android application to a web server. Though I used AsyncTask class and did the data transfer in background, for getting the result data back from server I used get() method of the AsyncTask class which makes the UI synchronous which means that your UI will be waiting for too long. So my advice is to make your app do every network oriented tasks on a separate thread.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. In my case I had 2 nested Relative Layouts. RelativeLayout always has to do two measure passes. If you nest RelativeLayouts, you get an exponential measurement algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

this usually happens when you are executing huge processes in main thread. it's OK to skip frames less than 200. but if you have more than 200 skipped frames, it can slow down your application UI thread. what you can do is to do these processes in a new thread called worker thread and after that, when you want to access and do something with UI thread(ex: do something with views, findView etc...) you can use **handler or runOnUiThread**(I like this more) in order to display the processing results.
this absolutely solves the problem. using worker threads are very useful or even must be used when it comes to this cases.

https://stacklearn.ir

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. When I ran the code on another computer, it worked fine. On mine, however, it displayed "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread".

I solved my problem by restarting Android studio [File -> Invalidated caches / Restart -> click on "Invalidate and Restart"].

Comment: I don't know why your solution worked. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually not an error. This happens when you have the debugger for a long time. Remove the brake point and check again.

Answer (score 1):

My app had same problem. But it was not doing other than displaying list of cards and text on it. Nothing running in background. But then after some investigation found that the image set for card background was causing this, even though it was small(350kb). Then I converted the image to 9patch images using 
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html. 

 This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because I had accidentally set a breakpoint on a method. Once I cleared it, the message went away and performance improved a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As I did first preferably use `SVG` images instead of all other types, If not possible compress all of your `PNG` and `JPG` resources using some image processing tools such as `Adobe Photoshop` or `Fotosizer`. one of the easiest ways is online image compressing tools like [this](https://compresspng.com/) which helped me to decrease all my image files to almost 50% of their initial size.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue while developing an app which uses a lot of drawable png files on grid layout. I also tried to optimize my code as far as possible.. but it didn't work out for me.. Then i tried to reduce the size of those png.. and guess its working absolutely fine.. So my suggestion is to reduce size of drawable resources if any..

Answer (score 0):

After doing much R&D on this issue I got the Solution,

In my case I am using Service that will run every 2 second and with the runonUIThread, I was wondering the problem was there but not at all.
The next issue that I found is that I am using large Image in may App and thats the problem.

I removed the Images and set new Images.

Conclusion :- Look into your code is there any raw file that you are using is of big size.

Answer (score 0):

First read the warning. It says more load on main thread. So what you have to do is just run functions with more work in a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have not resolved yet but will do. For my tiny project with one composable function (button) and logic to check if "com.whatsapp" packages exists on device (emulator) i have the following in the same log while **starting simulator**:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me that was RoundedBackgroundColorSpan ! in textview, I remove it so (burn my brain to find it because It doesn't appear in real smartphones like Pixel 4 Xl or Samsung note 10+ also in emulator but in chip device this slow a view).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by taking out async function calls in the main function.

Was doing some hacky things for dependency instantiation, along with async network requests.

Answer (score -2):

This is normal if you are using async/await functionalities in your application.