# Get value of BLE characteristic in GATT Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

I am Trying to read the characteristics and get its value using the following code

```
private byte[] val;

mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);// reads it
val=characteristic.getValue();
String s=new String(val);
```

My app crashes giving error "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

I have also tried

```
private String s;
 mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);// reads it
    s=characteristic.getStringValue(0);
```

but the error is same

I have debugged my code to check if its getting the value

```
private String s;
     mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);// reads it
        s=characteristic.getStringValue(0);
    system.out.println(s);
```

which displays the correct value but on Running the code as Android App. I get the same error.

Comment: If i remember correctly this might be because you are doing too much work on your main thread, you should do heavy processing in a separate Thread or by using a Runnable or an AsyncTask. This SO question might help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Comment: Ditto @Kyriakos.  You should run that code on another thread.  If you need to update the UI after that you can use `this.runOnUiThread() { ... }` to update your UI accordingly (assuming this refers to your Activity, or you can use `getActivity()` from a fragment in place of this).  You can also use `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(task);`  where task is the update to your UI.

Answer (score 5):

If i remember correctly this might be because you are doing too much work on your main thread, you should do heavy processing in a separate Thread or by using a Runnable or an AsyncTask. [This SO question might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

when you call Read
can get the characterstic from BluetoothGattCallback

```
BluetoothGattCallback mCallback=new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, 
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

    };
};
```