# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I start my app on emulator, I find this message>  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. It is the same situation when I start app on my phone. Its running, but slow. Does my phone and emulator work slow or I made a mistake in the code?

I saw that there are a lot of similar problem, but every problem has a different solution. Tnx a lot!

LogCat

```
12-24 18:11:37.923: I/ActivityThread(1385): Pub com.bogdanskoric.recnik.DictionaryProvider: com.bogdanskoric.recnik.DictionaryProvider
12-24 18:11:38.464: D/dalvikvm(1385): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 121K, 3% free 8263K/8455K, paused 125ms, total 129ms
12-24 18:11:38.486: I/dalvikvm-heap(1385): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.582MB for 1536016-byte allocation
12-24 18:11:38.594: D/dalvikvm(1385): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 3% free 9761K/9991K, paused 27ms+6ms, total 110ms
12-24 18:11:39.524: I/Choreographer(1385): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 18:11:39.723: D/gralloc_goldfish(1385): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-24 18:11:41.454: I/Choreographer(1385): Skipped 348 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 18:11:44.463: I/Choreographer(1385): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 18:11:46.124: I/Choreographer(1385): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

SearchableDictionary.java

```
package com.bogdanskoric.recnik;




        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
            Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
            wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
            startActivity(wordIntent);
        } 
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchable_dictionary, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(info); 
        searchView.setIconified(true);



        int searchDeleteImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ImageView searchDeleteImg = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchDeleteImgId);
        searchDeleteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_discard);

        int searchSrcTextId = getResources().getIdentifier( "android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchSrcTextId);
        searchEditText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
          return true;

    }
```

WordActivity.java

```
public class WordActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            finish();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
            TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);

            int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD);
            int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION);

            word.setText(cursor.getString(wIndex));
            definition.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
        }
    }
```

DictionaryProvider.java

public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {
    String TAG = "DictionaryProvider";

```
public static String AUTHORITY = "com.bogdanskoric.recnik.DictionaryProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");


public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                              "/vnd.bogdanskoric.recnik";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                   "/vnd.bogdanskoric.recnik";

private DictionaryDatabase mDictionary;

// UriMatcher stuff
private static final int SEARCH_WORDS = 0;
private static final int GET_WORD = 1;
private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    // to get definitions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
    // to get suggestions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);

    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    return matcher;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDictionary = new DictionaryDatabase(getContext());
    return true;
}


@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {

    // Use the UriMatcher to see what kind of query we have and format the db query accordingly
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return search(selectionArgs[0]);
        case GET_WORD:
            return getWord(uri);
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return refreshShortcut(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
    }
}

private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,

   /* SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
                    (only if you want to refresh shortcuts) */
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor search(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {

  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}


@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
        case GET_WORD:
            return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: only post relevant code and not your entire project

Comment: Tnx for the comment tyczj! I deleted some of them. I am not shure what exactly is relevant in this case. If you think that I need to delete more codes, please tell me.

Comment: try with a simple app (basic hello world) to test if your emulator has a problem or the code.

Comment: run this `Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);` on a worker thread.

Comment: @thepace it is similar problem with other basic app. It si problably cause emulator is slow, tnx for suggestion.

Comment: @mmlooloo tnx for comment! this code exist in WorkActivity, but mangedQuery is deprecated (crossed out)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, I see messages like that all the time on the emulator, and there's no issue on a device.

Comment: Tnx @nasch! I agree with you, it is important то work :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this question, it's documented well here: [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread/21126690#21126690).