# How do I extract data from multiple related web pages in Android using Jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup, web-scraping

Well, I have been working in a app to display news headings and contents from the site http://www.myagdikali.com

I am able to extract the data from 'myagdikali.com/category/news/national-news/' but there are only 10 posts in this page and there are links to other pages as 1,2,3... like myagdikali.com/category/news/national-news/page/2.

All I need to know is, how do I extract news from every possible pages under /national_news ? Is it even possible using Jsoup ?

Till now my code to extract data from a single page is:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
    int i = getArguments().getInt(NEWS);
    String topics = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topics)[i];

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            url = "http://myagdikali.com/category/news/national-news";
            new NewsExtractor().execute();

            break;
            .....


[EDIT]
private class NewsExtractor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   String title;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    while (status == OK) {
        currentURL = url + String.valueOf(page);


        try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(currentURL).execute();
            status = response.statusCode();
            if (status == OK) {

                Document doc = response.parse();
                Elements urlLists = doc.select("a[rel=bookmark]");
                for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element urlList : urlLists) {

                    String src = urlList.text();

                    myLinks.add(src);

                }
                title = doc.title();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    page++;

    }
    return null;




}
```

**EDIT:**
While trying to extract data from single page without loop, I can extract the data. But after using while loop, I get the error stating No adapter attached.

Actually I am loading the extracted data in the RecyclerView and onPostExecute is like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new     MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),myLinks);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);


    }
```

Comment: Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510578/no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the `URL` of the pages you need - http://myagdikali.com/category/news/national-news/page/X (where X is the page number between 2 and 446), you can loop through the `URL`s. You'll also need to use the Jsoup's `response`, to make sure that the page exists (the number 446 can be changed - I believe that it increases).
The code should be something like this:

```
final String URL = "http://myagdikali.com/category/news/national-news/page/";
final int OK = 200;
String currentURL;
int page = 2;
int status = OK;
Connection.Response response = null;
Document doc = null;

while (status == OK) {
    currentURL = URL + String.valueOf(page);  //add the page number to the url
    response = Jsoup.connect(currentURL)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .execute();  //you may add here userAgent/timeout etc.
    status = response.statusCode();
    if (status == OK) {
        doc = response.parse();
        //extract the info. you need
    }
    page++;
}
```

This is of course not fully working code - you'll have to add `try-catch` sentences, but the compiler will help you.
Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**
1.  I've editted the code - I've had to send a `userAgent` string in order to get response from the server.
2. The code runs on my machine, it prints lots of `????`, because I don't have the proper fonts installed.
3. The error you're getting is from the `Android` part - something to do with your `view`s. You haven't posted that piece of code...
4. Try to add the `userAgent`, it might solve it.
5. Please add the error and the code you're running to the original question by editting it, it's much more readable.

Comment: It's still not working. Now I am getting this error.
07-18 17:03:10.967    4708-4708/np.info.roshan.benionline_webportal E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Let's try to pinpoint the problem: after the line `String src = urlList.text()` add the line `Log.d("NEWS", src);`. This will (hopefully) print the lines you're extracting to the `LogCat`. If you can see those lines in your Log, then my answer solved your original question and your new problem is the `RecyclerView`. Try to search for this error in google, I'm sure you'll find a solution. If you don't get the lines printed in the Log, will have to go on and fix it...

Comment: Okay wait!! I am getting more errors :D I m gonna try this.

Comment: Yes Sir!! @GDG .. I can get data in LogCat. So there is problem in the RecyclerView. But I am able to extract data from single page (without loop) with the same code right now in RecyclerView.

Comment: Then I think that I've solved your **original** question, and you should open a new question with the new problem.