# No adapter attached; skipping layout with Fragments and Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

In my project I use Compose in Fragments.

My FirstScreenFragment:

```
class FirstScreenFragment : Fragment() {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val viewPager = activity?.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager)
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                OnBoardingPage(
                    viewPager = viewPager,
                    backgroundColor = R.color.light_green,
                    fragmentPicture = R.drawable.first_fragment_picture,
                    title = "Fitness Client Tracker",
                    textContent = "Welcome",
                    currentPage = 1
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

And after second fragment:

> W/ssclienttracke: Class
> androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList failed lock
> verification and will run slower.
> Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
> and incorrect proguard optimizations.

I don't see any fragments skipped but why is this happening?

**EDIT:**
ViewPagerFragment:

```
return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    setContent {
        val fragmentList = arrayListOf(
            FirstScreenFragment(),
            SecondScreenFragment(),
            ThirdScreenFragment()
        )
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(
            fragmentList,
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
            lifecycle
        )
        AndroidView(factory = { context ->
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null, false)
            val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager)
            viewPager.adapter = adapter
            view
        })
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    list: ArrayList<Fragment>,
    fm: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {
    private val fragmentList = list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }
}
```

Still didn't find the right solution, so if u know write it.

Comment: Why it is happening? Because RecyclerView is attached before it has an adapter attached to it. Is it some critical error and can be mostly ignored? Yes. [This could help you answer the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510578/no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: Any updates about this? I have the similar problem, after few hours of research I found that it happen in my app only after I enable compose in module.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I switched fully to Compose and made onboarding without ViewPager + some of guys on Android discord channel said that library was always buggy.