# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. Even though I have used Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            initJourneyStatusList();
            adapterJourneyStatus = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listJourneyStatus) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/calibri.ttf"));
                    ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    return v;
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/calibri.ttf"));
                    ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    return v;
                }
            };
            adapterJourneyStatus.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerJourneyStatus.setAdapter(adapterJourneyStatus);
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

I have inserted this code inside onCreate function. and When I run the application, it is still slow and lagging. When I use debugger, it shows me "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.". Is there any other way to perform tasks on background or implement multi-threading.

Comment: initialize-set your adapter in OnPostExecute() instead of doInBackground()

Comment: @HareshChhelana is correct, accessing UI components from a background thread is not supported in android. Not an solution to the problem, though. Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread#answer-21126690?

Comment: As others have suggested, something seems wrong. You should be crashing by trying to call `setAdapter()` on a background thread. Also, do not use `getApplicationContext()` here. With regards to the time that you are spending, use Traceview to determine exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the good comments others already said, you are creating (on the UI thread) the typefaces many time (at least once for every list row), and this is a slow operation. Create the typefaces only once and save them as local member variables

Answer (score 1):

doInBackground() is not run in UI thread so you can not do any UI thread stuff in it, So try to move adapter initialization and set code in OnPostExecute().

```
private void setJourneyStatusList(final Context context){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                initJourneyStatusList();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                adapterJourneyStatus = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listJourneyStatus) {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/calibri.ttf"));
                        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                        return v;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
                        View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/calibri.ttf"));
                        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                        return v;
                    }
                };
                adapterJourneyStatus.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerJourneyStatus.setAdapter(adapterJourneyStatus);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using singleton classes in order to reduce number of repeated slow operations. For example, Loading fonts is a slow operations. Try singleton class like,

```
public class ClassName {
    private static ClassName instance;
    public TypeFace fontToLoad;

    public static ClassName getInstance() {
         if (instance == null)
               instance = new ClassName();
         return instance;
    }

    public void loadFonts(Activity activity) {
         fontToLoad = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/calibri.ttf");
    }

    public TypeFace font() {
         return fontToLoad;
    }
}
```

Now, use this singleton class at the starting of the application (i.e. launcher activity) to load fonts as,

```
private ClassName className = ClassName.getInstance();
```

And in onCreate function,

```
className.loadFonts(this);
```

And now where you want to use fonts, use it like,

```
private ClassName className = ClassName.getInstance();
```

and for editText or any view,

```
editText.setTypeFace(className.font());
```

This will load fonts only once throughout application and can be used several times. This may help you with many other functions other than just loading fonts.