# Android Multi-Threading work

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm working in a application that I have a button to login, which checks if this account exists already in the database  and if so, go to the next activity.

But nothing is showing in the layout screen.

The log cat is repeating the following message:

> Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

What is causing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Take some time studying how process and threads work on an Android system. It worth the effort.

Quoting a specific sentence related to your issue:

> When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction,
>   this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you
>   implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is
>   happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network
>   access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is
>   blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From
>   the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse,
>   if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5
>   seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous
>   "application not responding" (ANR) dialog. The user might then decide
>   to quit your application and uninstall it if they are unhappy.

Good luck !