# Android I/Choreographer: Skipped xxx frames

Tags: android, json

I'm implementing an app with Android Studio.
I have a use case as below:
When a user clicks on navigation drawer, I inflate a Fragment into main_activity.
So, I get the needed data from a server as JSON and insert it into SQLite and I finally populate the Fragment.
I used an AsyncTask Class to read the JSON and insert the data

```
 public class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
                queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        Constants.URL_ADVERTISEMENTS,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(final String response) {
                                try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                    writeDataToDB();
                                    loadDataFromLocalDataBase();

                                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT);
                                    SharedPreferences setting = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTING_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
                                    String now = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                                    editor.putString(Constants.LAST_ADVERTISEMENT_SYNC_DATE, now);
                                    editor.commit();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "DEVELOPER:" + e.getMessage());
                                } 

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse occured :" + error.getMessage());

                    }
                });

                stringRequest.setTag(TAG);
                queue.add(stringRequest);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Load data has error:" + e.getMessage());

            }
            return null;
        }


    }`
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to debug an 'info' log?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I wrap body of onResponse method with an AsyncTask and my problem solved .