# Perform multithreading when initializing fragments in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am creating a basic application with navigation drawer and fragments.I am initializing all the fragments at once and hide them at start and according to user click I am showing required fragments.It runs perfectly but it generates message **Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**.I have read about it,that we should use sepreate thread for performing long running operations.But in my application i am not doing such thing and still it generates this message.

This is my code:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mContext = HomeActivity.this;
        HomeMenuButtonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.HomeMenuButtonLayout);
        HomeMenuButtonLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
        // load slide menu items

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_item);
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_item_icon);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
        }

        // Set Header Right Drawer
        LayoutInflater inflaters = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup headertop = (ViewGroup) inflaters.inflate(R.layout.list_home_header, mDrawerList,
                false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headertop, null, false);

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems, "yes");
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        setLastFragmentTag("HOME");
        setTitleText("Home");

        Fragment Fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, Fragment1, getLastFragmentTag());
        transaction.commit();

        Fragment Fragment2 = new FriendListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, Fragment2, "Friends");
        transaction.hide(Fragment2);
        transaction1.commit();

        Fragment Fragment3 = new ChatFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, Fragment3, "Chat");
        transaction.hide(Fragment3);
        transaction2.commit();

        Fragment Fragment4 = new SettingsFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction3.add(R.id.frame_container, Fragment4, "SETTINGS");
        transaction3.hide(Fragment4);
        transaction3.commit();

        Fragment Fragment5 = new Fragment5();
        FragmentTransaction transaction4 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction4.add(R.id.frame_container, Fragment5, "PURCHASE");
        transaction4.hide(Fragment5);
        transaction4.commit();

        Fragment Fragment6 = new PurchasedHistoryFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction5 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction5.add(R.id.frame_container, Fragment6, "SALES");
        transaction5.hide(Fragment6);
        transaction5.commit();

        Fragment Fragment7 = new NewsAndOffersFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction6 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction6.add(R.id.frame_container, Fragment7, "OFFER");
        transaction6.hide(Fragment7);
        transaction6.commit();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                if (position == 1) {
                    openFragment("HOME");
                    setTitleText("Home");
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    openFragment("Friends");
                    setTitleText("Friends");
                }

                if (position == 6) {
                    //openFragment(new NewsAndOffersFragment());
                    openFragment("Chat");
                    setTitleText("Chat");
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    // openFragment(new ChatFragment());
                    openFragment("SETTINGS");
                    setTitleText("SETTINGS");
                }

                if (position == 8) {
                    openFragment("SETTINGS");
                    setTitleText("Settings");
                }

                if (position == 4) {
                    //openFragment(new Fragment5());
                    openFragment("PURCHASE");
                    setTitleText("PURCHASE");
                }

                if (position == 5) {
                    // openFragment(new PurchasedHistoryFragment());
                    openFragment("SALES");
                    setTitleText("SALES");
                }
            }
        });


            public void openFragment(final String currentTag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (currentTag == getLastFragmentTag()) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                } else {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentTag));
                    transaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getLastFragmentTag()));
                    transaction.commit();
                }
                setLastFragmentTag(currentTag);
            }
        }, 300);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }
}
```

so my question is,how to put and what part of code should i put on seperate thread.I am not using any api till now.

Comment: Until your app is working smooth there is no issue with this warning

Comment: Kindly check answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Comment: There's nothing in your code that needs to be done on a worked thread, however keeping this many Fragments in memory with just one of them being visible doesn't seem like a good idea. Try to rethink your approach.

Comment: @Egor i know this approach is not good but i wanted to use the same object of the fragments every time,In my previous code i was creating new object every time when user click on drawer menu items