# "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" only without video output connected

Tags: android, multithreading, hdmi

I'm having a strange issue when I run my application from Android Studio on my device. When the HDMI cable of my device (e.g. Odroid) is disconnected (no other video output connected), I found in Logcat this error "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread". When a monitor is plugged the error did not show anymore.

Do you think is something related to the code or just a random error not relevant?

PS I need to use my app without video output.

PPS The error appears only when the monitor is not plugged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that , there is some waiting mechanism in your code , So I suggest you to shift your code into `AsyncTask` so you will never encounter this error.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Do you think is not related to the video output connected? Because I just used different Threads and AsyncTask too.

Comment: Yes I think you have written some code to detect Video device or something related to that, So after disconnecting with HDMI you are getting error.

Comment: So it's OS related? I'm using an Odroid device

Comment: might be YES, and could you please share your error log or code.