# SQLite Android update a specific row

Tags: android, sqlite, content-values

I'm having trouble trying to update a row in SQlite.

I want to update the row "name" with anyone with the name1 and rename it to bob.
I also want to update row "age" with anyone who is 5.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("age", "bob"); 
cv.put("name", "2");
database.update("tblTest1", cv, "name", null);

cursor = database.rawQuery("select age,name from tblTest1", null);
displayAllInCursor(cursor);
```

When I run this the rest of the program works fine. In the logcat the following message is displayed:

> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Also I'm unsure how to create a delete with `ContentValues`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: For the log message, please see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Comment: wrap your database calls in an AsyncTask. the message is warning you that something is taking too much time in the UI thread - you should try to keep it idle. if there's any chance something is going to take a moment or two, use a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just update where clause.

```
 String where = "name ='name1'OR age = 5" ;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("age", "bob"); 
        cv.put("name", "2");
        database.update("tblTest1", cv, where, null);

        cursor = database.rawQuery("select age,name from tblTest1", null);
        displayAllInCursor(cursor);
```

Answer (score -1):

do it this way:

```
String[] args = new String[]{yourVariableName}; //this is for the condition
database.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLENAME + " SET colum1Name='" + variable1 + "', column2Name='"+variable2+"' WHERE id=?", args);//replace id for your condition
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "database updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `db.update` method, just the conditional needs to be correct