# Android - Application may be doing to much work on its main thread

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, imageview, lag

I know that I have to much going on in my main thread but I'm looking for a work-around.

Here is my app's structure:

Currently I have my main activity, which has 6 clickable imageviews (that open new activities), the problem happens when one of the activities are opened. In this activity I'm using a SlidingTabLayout with 3 tabs.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

I'm creating a piano out of drawables(shapes)

For example, this is the black key:

```
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FF000000" />

    <solid 
      android:color="#FF000000"/>
</shape>
```

Then I call this drawables in my layout to create the piano:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10.5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/key_black" />
```

I'm displaying 7 Imageviews for the black keys and 10 Imageviews for the white keys PER piano and I have 11 pianos PER tab. So that is 187 Imageview per tab.

So I understand that this will be harsh on my CPU. I'm looking for a way to do this of my main thread? To do it in the background? To do it without experiencing lagging?

Comment: Can you provide an Image of what it should look like and explain what you want to achive/ what it should do? Apparently you want the user to interact with the keys of the piano? But 187 interactable items seem a little much to have on one screen

Comment: I just want to display the piano's, i don't want the user to interact with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Comment: Why do you need the keys to be in individual imageviews then? How about creating the piano as a whole in a .png or by using Android shapes and then put it in one imageView? Or should it animate?

Comment: Every piano show different keys that are pressed, so every piano looks different, so using one png of a piano won't work. Using multiple png's for each piano will cause the same problem.

Comment: If you could provide an image of how it should look, it would be easier to help. Anyway, if you just need an image for each different piano, I would create a base image (all keys not pressed) and then draw the selected keys onto it via a [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). Depends of course how those pressed Keys should look

Comment: here is a link to a image of what I want to achieve: https://postimg.org/image/ow7zxwswn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mentioned above, I would create a base image for the piano, and adjust it according to the currently pressed keys. The code below shows the general idea: Load the base image from R.drawable, use the indices for the pressed keys, as well as the size of the image to create [Paths](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html), draw the Paths, return the image. If you need clearification, let me know.

```
public Bitmap getPianoImage(Context context, int[] pressedKeyIndices){
    Bitmap pianoImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.pianoBase);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pianoImage);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    for(int pressedKeyIndex : pressedKeyIndices){
        Path path = getPathForKeyIndex(pressedKeyIndex, pianoImage.getWidth(), pianoImage.getHeight());
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    return pianoImage;
}

private Path getPathForKeyIndex(int idx, int w, int h){

    Path path = new Path();

    switch(idx){
        case 0:
            path.moveTo(0f*w, 0f*h); // used for first point
            path.lineTo(0f*w, 1f*h);
            path.lineTo(0.1f*w, 1f*h);
            path.lineTo(0.1f*w, 0.5f*h);
            path.lineTo(0.08f*w, 0.5f*h);
            path.lineTo(0.08f*w, 0f*h);
            path.lineTo(0f*w, 0f*h);
            break;
        case 1: ...
    }

    return path;
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what I should do in my xml?

Comment: You don't need any xml file. Put the base image of the piano (only black and white) in the `R.drawable` folder (-> `R.drawable.pianoBase`). And then use the code above (that needs to be completed) to create a Bitmap. The Bitmap takes the base image and colors the areas that correspond to ne indecies that you pass in as an argument of the function.

Comment: I've placed the image in R.drawable and I've pasted your code in but nothing happens, can't see the image.. I understand what you are saying but I cant see the image

Comment: Well first of all, the code above needs to be completed. You need to specify a path for each of the 17 keys in the `getPathForKeyIndex(int idx, int w, int h)` function. The path needs to trace the outline of each key in the image. Then, if you want to display an image with keys 1 and 4 pressed (for example), you pass those as an Array to the `getPianoImage(Context context, int[] pressedKeyIndices)` function. The function returns the Bitmap that you can display then

Comment: Ok I got it working. I duplicated it to test if there is a improvement in performance and there is still no improvement.

Comment: Can you please edit your current code into your intial post? Please show the complete code (that is relevant) for creating the fragment