# Loading an Image using Picasso

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm using `Picasso` to load an `Image` from a `URL`, After I run the application I get to see that "Application may be doing too much work on its main thread". To set the `Image` I'm writing some thing like this :

```
Picasso.with(ScrollingActivity.this).load(photoUrl).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(userProfileImageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                with(ScrollingActivity.this).load(photoUrl).into(userProfileImageView);
            }
        });
```

Now I'm thinking to use `AsyncTask` to set the `Image` into `ImageView` and for that I modified my code to something like :

But now I don't know what to write in `doInBackground` method and `onPostExecute` method.

I used the `AsyncTask` method like this :

```
class SetImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                Picasso.with(ScrollingActivity.this).load(photoUrl).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(userProfileImageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        with(ScrollingActivity.this).load(photoUrl).into(userProfileImageView);
                    }
                });


                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        }
```

But the problem is that I'm setting the Image into the `ImageView` in the `doInBackground` method. So I think that needs to be done in UI thread. Can you please tell me how do I set the `Image` using `AsyncTask`

Comment: Try the regular way. `Picasso.with(ScrollingActivity.this).load(photoUrl).into(userProfileImageView);` and without asynctask.

Comment: The regular way may be causing heavy work in the main UI, so I thing thats the reason I'm getting "Application may be doing too much work on UI thread". I even have many more Images to load using Picasso so that's way I was thing to use AsyncTask

Comment: Why are you using networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) ?

Comment: to load the data offline if the data is present offline

Comment: Simply just write your onPostExecute or remove AsyncTask and write direct code.

Comment: Picasso has its own Asynchronous mechanism already, I would think that the issue is caused by other factor.

Comment: @Enzokie Thanks ..

Comment: If you see this in logcat: `Application may be doing too much work on its main thread`, that can be normal. I can see this even with simplest apps, because every app is doing a lot of work initializing the application when it starts. Picasso is pretty optimized, so  I wouldn't try to overengineer it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `AsyncTask` or and background Thread to load image using `Piccaso`. Picasso is already optimized. It has its own Asynchronous calls. The problem that you are getting

> "Application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

is not due to the Picasso. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread) link to see reason behind `"Application may be doing too much work on its main thread"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Target` then you don't need an `AsyncTask` as it will decode in the background.

```
private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) { 
         //do whatever you need in here      
      }

    @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed() {
      }
}

private void loadBitmap() {
   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
}
```

Make sure you're binding the `Target` to a view otherwise it can be garbage collected before the process is complete.

Comment: can you please tell how this works and how this is downloading the image off UI thread?