# How to view profile after login in android JSON MySQL?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I tried to view profile of the user that login. But I get a tremendouos error and my application stop working. I am new to this android development. I try to use listview in JSON and MySQL

this is my ViewProfileActivity

```
package com.teradata.sb186103.cbet;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private JSONParser jsonParser;
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
String id;
String consId;
private EditText etName;
private EditText etPassword;
private EditText etEmail;
String name;
String email;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);

    String PREFS_NAME = "LOGIN";
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    consId = settings.getString("consId", "");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    id = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.ID);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv5);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv7);

    try {

        String[] arr =  GetConsumerDetails(id);

        String val1 = arr[0];
        String val2 = arr[1];
        String val3 = arr[2];

        etName.setText(val1);
        etEmail.setText(val2);
        etPassword.setText(val3);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void Update(View v) {
    try {

        name = etName.getText().toString();
        email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        Boolean update = UpdateProfile(id, name, email, consId, password);
        if(update==true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PROFILE HAS BEEN UPDATED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CreateProfile2Activity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR OCCURRED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean UpdateProfile(String id, String name, String email, String consId, String password) throws Exception{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String URL = JSONParser.serverURL;
    String tag = "updateProfile";

    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String value = id + "<@>" + name + "<@>" + email + "<@>" + consId + "<@>" + password;
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", value));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);

    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


public String[] GetConsumerDetails(String id) throws Exception{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String URL = JSONParser.serverURL;
    String tag = "getConsumerDetails";

    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String value = id;
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", value));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl (URL, params);

    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
        String list = json.getString("list");
        String[] arr = list.split("#");
        return arr;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public  void done(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public  void bankDetails(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateProfile2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

This is my index.php. Please refer to the Get Consumer Details tag. I got an error at  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)). [image: FYI this is my table looks like]

```
<?php

 require_once ('database.php');
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); 

 if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {

$tag = $_POST['tag'];  
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0); 

//LOGIN
if ($tag == 'consumerLogin') {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $array = explode("<@>", $value);
    $consEmail = $array[0];
    $password = $array[1];

    $query = "select * from consumer where consEmail='$consEmail' and password='$password'";    
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row[0] != null)
        $response["success"] = 1;
    else
        $response["success"] = 0;
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;             
}

//GET ROW ID
else if ($tag == 'getID') {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $array = explode("<@>", $value);
    $table = $array[0];
    $column = $array[1];
    $val = $array[2];       

    $query = "select id from $table where $column = '$val'";    
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row[0] != null) {
        $response["value"] = $row[0];
        $response["success"] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;     
}

//CHECK PROFILE
else if ($tag == 'CheckProfile') {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $array = explode("<@>", $value);
    $consName= $array[0];
    $consEmail = $array[1];
    $password = $array[2];

    $query = ("select * from consumer where consEmail=$consEMail") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
    $found=false;
    if($row[0]!=null)
        $found=true;

    if($found==true) {          
        $response["success"] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    return;             
}

//REGISTER PROFILE
else if ($tag == 'RegisterProfile') {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $array = explode("<@>", $value);
    $id= $array[0];
    $consName = $array[1];
    $consEmail = $array[2];
    $password = $array[3];  

    $query = "insert into consumer values(null,'$consName','$consEmail','$password')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);  

    $response["success"] = 1;                       
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;             
}

//GET CONSUMER DETAILS
else if ($tag == 'getConsumerDetails') {
    $value = $_POST['value'];

    $query = "select consName, consEmail, password from consumer where id=$value";
    $result = mysql_query($query);      
    $list="";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $list = $list . $row['consName'] . "#" . $row['consEmail'] . "#" . $row['password'] ."<@>";

    }
    $response["success"] = 1;  
    $response["list"] = $list;          
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;         
}

  else {
      echo "Error Message: Invalid Request";        
   }
  }
  else {
    echo "Error Message: Anonymous Access Denied";  
}
 ?>
```

For the logcat. I got many error even saying that Android FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.

```
    10-10 02:33:46.589 10541-10541/com.teradata.sb186103.cbet I/Choreographer: Skipped 398 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-10 02:33:46.839 10541-10556/com.teradata.sb186103.cbet E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae831310
    10-10 02:33:49.628 10541-10541/com.teradata.sb186103.cbet D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    10-10 02:33:49.628 10541-10541/com.teradata.sb186103.cbet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.teradata.sb186103.cbet, PID: 10541
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teradata.sb186103.cbet/com.teradata.sb186103.cbet.ViewProfileActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
                                                                            at com.teradata.sb186103.cbet.ViewProfileActivity.onCreate(ViewProfileActivity.java:51)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my activity_view_profile.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.teradata.sb186103.cbet.ViewProfileActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="your profile"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="#B71C1C"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_round"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="fffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:maxLength="50"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_round"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv4"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="gggggg"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv5"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_round"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv6"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="12"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv7"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Update Your Bank Details"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:onClick="bankDetails"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv8"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_button"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:onClick="Update"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)? Also, a big fat [Bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) in `$query = "select * from consumer where consEmail='$consEmail' and password='$password'";`

Comment: thats in my login query. but it works fine @adrian-colomitchi

Comment: "but it works fine" Until someone passes to you a password of `Robert');drop table $table; --` and then it will work once... but probably not as intended. Do yourself a favour and read about `SQL injection attacks`. Here's [a starter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I see, but it doesnt solve my issue to view the profile details. Thanks anyway

Comment: Have you looked of what I linked to?

Comment: yes, I understands now. I try to use PDO. Nevertheless, I try debug my app, then I found after I login, it return null for all of the variable above.