# Android Program works but getting message in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I have a program that I have written that will calculate a value based on which other two values as input. The program works as I intend.

However, I am seeing a message when the emulator runs that says `I/Choreographer: Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`
Does anyone know what causes this? And more importantly what I need to do to fix it.

I am also seeing `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f773b061580.`

Comment: You can ignore `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked` message because it's only a message from the device, not your program. Meanwhile, `I/Choreographer: Skipped` could be related with your code and also could be just a message from your device. But with your description, that can't be from your code.

Comment: gooooooooogle It man http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread