# Android app crash while accessing data from firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While running my app on my android phone through the android debugger my app runs properly. But as I build the apk file & install it on my phone it crashes while accessing data from firebase realtime database. I don't know what to do?

Comment: You should try to add any logs you get when running the app on a real device via adb installation.

Comment: I doubt that my activity time is high as the i get  logs such as :                    V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 238480646
I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: What is the version of your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Without any logs it's insane to give you a helpful answer, but mostly the reason for crashes is the internet permissions at the manifest or some forgotten activities. Also you need for Firebase read and write permission to the storage of the device.

Comment: I have attached my comments please go through it:                                   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 238480646 I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. –

Comment: Please check this post to edit your post with the useful log 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

Step 1:

First add this in your gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

***Then***

Create an Application Class , like `MyApplication`, then :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private Context c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();



    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }


}
```

***Then finally go to your Manifest and do the following:***

```
<application
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```