# Aplication may be doing to much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I got an application who has count up to ten and show each number in a textView. Its only a sample for another Code. But the problem: when I start the app there comes nothing for a view times, and then comes a message "app isn't responding ". The log says "the application may be doing to much work on its main thread". When I searched I see there are many questions and answers to the theme "update TextView by new thread/handler..." and I've tried many examples-but nothing works. I'm new in programming and hope someone can tell me what's wrong. Maybe its easy but I don't know how to get it. Thanks for any help! Here is the code of the example:

```
package de.androidnewcomer.animation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static de.androidnewcomer.animation.R.id.textView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,Runnable {
private TextView textView;
private int i;
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    handler=new Handler();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    count();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            count();
            break;
    }
}
public void count() {
    while (i < 10) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("" + i);
        handler.postDelayed(this,1000);

    }
}
}
```

Edit: I update the count()- method and increased int I but now the output is only "10"... Thanks for the fast answers! here is the method now:

```
public void count() {
i=0;
while (i < 10) {
    i++;
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("" + i);
    handler.postDelayed(this,1000);

}
}
```

The app has to Show the numbers from one up to ten every second in the TextView.
But when I start  the app it shows only ten.
Thanks for all help

Comment: Because i never increments and you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Add `i++;` in your while loop

Answer (score 2):

First, i doesn't increment obviously and you have infinite loop because of that. Correct it.

Second, don't call `findViewById(`) again and again. It is quite time taking.
Call it once and initialize the `TextView` once in `onCreate()` instead.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Like this
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    handler=new Handler();
}
```

Third, do any long running operation like this in Background, like [using an Async task](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Ex:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

So, in your case, update the `TextView` with the incremented value of i in `onPostExecute()`(if you want to increment all at once and update once) or `onProgressUpdate()`(if you want to increment somewhat and post progress in between)

**Recommended read**: [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 1):

You don't increase i variable in your code. So, while(i < 10){} is a infinity loop.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't incremented the value of i in your code. You can do it like this:

```
while (i < 10) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("" + i);
    i++;
    handler.postDelayed(this,1000);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create a separate thread for long running actions in the context of GUI applications. Please take a look [Android-API](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // a potentially  time consuming task
        final Bitmap bitmap =
                processBitMap("image.png");
        mImageView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

}

The important thing is this:

```
  mImageView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
```

There is a new thread created that keeps your UI responsive and the task done at the same time.

Comment: Incorporate the "i never incrementing" bit in the background thread and I shall upvote for sure.

Comment: Only thing is, this is not the correct answer. The problem is that it is an infinite loop because his variable `i` never increases. This does not solve the problem at all.

Comment: There is new Thread(). Is it not background with respect to the main thread?

Comment: By using `new Thread()` you're doing something in the background and not on the main UI thread.... Yeah the downvote is appropriate

Comment: Are you talking about the same question?

Comment: *No* ?, we are talking about your answer.

Comment: I just showed how to do long running tasks. I dont know what the implementation of the count method should look like.