# ImageView.src in layout XML blocks main thread

Tags: android, android-image

I wanted a picture background. When I set the background property of the root element to the picture, it was distorted due to aspect ratio difference. After reading StackOverflow answers, I changed it to,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/wallpaper1"/>
```

The image is a 300KB full HD image. It looks good, but the problem is that when I start the activity, there is a stutter and a warning message.

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

When I removed the ImageView, there was no such problem. Should I not use 'src' in the layout XML, and load the image on my own using a background thread?

Comment: Have you read this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Comment: I know what it means, but the point is that imageview.src is not my code. It is in a layout XML that is loaded by the Android framework. So I was wondering if there already is an in-built solution for this kind of thing in the framework, or I should not use 'src' and load the image on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert image in to [.webp](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html) format to reduce image size, and use lossless encoding type to keep image quality.

In Android Studio

**1.** [right click on image asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f5hO.png)

**2.** [click Convert to WebP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ5ko.png)

**3.** Choose use lossless encoding and tap (API 18+)

Comment: I reckon this is an image dimension problem, not a file format problem.