# Too much work in main thread from a Thread in Service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-threads

I am making an app where you run a thread in a service and it checks the current foreground package using this [library](https://github.com/ricvalerio/foregroundappchecker/)

Service Code:

```
public class CheckService extends Service {

long startTime;
long stopTime;

boolean shouldRun = true;

private static final String TAG = "CheckService";

final AppChecker appChecker = new AppChecker();

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v(TAG,"Thread is still running");
        while(shouldRun){
            Log.v(TAG,"Process running is "+ appChecker.getForegroundApp(getApplicationContext()));
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= stopTime){
                shouldRun = false;
                stopSelf();
                return;
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    stopTime = intent.getLongExtra("stop-time",0);

    if (stopTime == 0){
        stopSelf();
    }else{

        Log.v(TAG," Thread is started at "+ String.valueOf(startTime));

        new Thread(runnable).run();
    }

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.v(TAG,"Service is destroyed");
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Basically, I want the thread to run for a given duration given by the user.

When the thread stops after the given duration is over, my app crashes while showing this error

```
01-10 17:26:08.541 23317-23317/com.sriram.donotdisturb I/Choreographer: 
Skipped 1207 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its 
main thread.
01-10 17:26:08.567 23317-23324/com.sriram.donotdisturb I/art: Wrote 
stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Most of the code is in the thread. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14678593/5110595)

Comment: Its not a duplicate because our situations are different

Answer (score 1):

you should use `start` instead of `run`. `run` executes the run method. You need to use `start()` for the thread to begin is execution. Alternatively you can use an `IntentService`, that is already able to handle asynchronous requests

Comment: I didn't even notice that. Thanks. I know about Intent Service. I was just curious about how it'll work in started service