# My app crashes whenever my EditText is empty and I press a button

Tags: java, android, crash-reports

The problem is that each time I click on the button in my app, then whenever one of my `EditText` or both are empty, the app will crash.

The idea is that I will write the calories in the `EditText` called caloriesIn and it will put out an `int` in the `caloriesOut` which is a textfield. 
The same idea goes for "fat".

The problem just to sum up is that if I write something in the calories, but don't write anything in fat, or just don't write anything in either of them, the app will crash.

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText caloriesIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caloriesIn);
                EditText fatIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fatIn);
                TextView caloriesOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caloriesOut);
                TextView fatOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fatOut);

                int calories = Integer.parseInt(caloriesIn.getText().toString());
                int fat = Integer.parseInt(fatIn.getText().toString());
                int caloriesResult = calories;
                int fatResult = fat;

                caloriesOut.setText(caloriesResult + "");
                fatOut.setText(fatResult + "");


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Crash report:

> 03-22 17:20:02.512 22193-22193/ottolopez.healthynote I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   03-22 17:20:02.556 22193-22193/ottolopez.healthynote V/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring 0 children of 1073741833
>   03-22 17:20:02.561 22193-22193/ottolopez.healthynote I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2936 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
>   03-22 17:20:05.047 22193-22193/ottolopez.healthynote D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   03-22 17:20:05.049 22193-22193/ottolopez.healthynote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: ottolopez.healthynote, PID: 22193
>                                                                          java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
>                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
>                                                                              at ottolopez.healthynote.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Add the crash report in question .

Comment: Where do i find that?

Comment: @Otto it would be in the logcat window in android studio right after the app crashes

Comment: how do i edit my post though?

Comment: there is edit button below your question ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this methode on your activity :

```
public boolean isParsable(String input){
    boolean parsable = true;
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(input);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        parsable = false;
    }
    return parsable;
}
```

Then updated your code like this :

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText caloriesIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caloriesIn);
                EditText fatIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fatIn);
                TextView caloriesOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caloriesOut);
                TextView fatOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fatOut);
                String caloriesString = caloriesIn.getText().toString();
                int calories = 0;
                if (isParsable(caloriesString)){
                    calories = Integer.parseInt(caloriesString);
                    int caloriesResult = calories;
                    caloriesOut.setText(caloriesResult + "");
                }

                String fatString = caloriesIn.getText().toString();
                int fat = 0;
                if (isParsable(fatString)){
                    fat = Integer.parseInt(fatString);
                    int fatResult = fat;
                    fatOut.setText(fatResult + "");
                }

            }
        });

    }


    public static boolean isParsable(String input){
        boolean parsable = true;
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(input);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            parsable = false;
        }
        return parsable;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice it works exept for the fatct that each time i put a variabel into  only one of the EditText's it also changes the other

Comment: Sorry i did a small mistake, see the updated code again

Comment: It's fine now ?

Comment: I'm sorry. It almost works but whenever i type a number in one of the EitText's it changes both of the TextFields, buti might be able to solve that my self later. Thank you :)

Comment: didn't seem to change anything. Btw I really appreciate your help

Comment: Okay, happy to help

Comment: Still does changes both of the textFields

Comment: I've found the problem, check now

Comment: It still changes them, but i'll just figure it out my self i think. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: i just noticed that i did   `String caloriesString = caloriesIn.getText().toString();` and   `String fatString = caloriesIn.getText().toString();` the sencond one should be `String fatString = fatIn.getText().toString();` sorry :\

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `Integer.parseInt()` doesn't handle empty string which is not a number. So, you need to check for text emptiness and then use `Integer.parseInt()`. Also you can use isDigitsOnly method before using parseInt.

Comment: Ok, so how do i check for text emptiness?

Comment: You can use the handy method TextUtils.isEmpty(caloriesIn.getText().toString()). If it returns false, you can use parseInt. Also use digits as the inputType for the edit text so that user can enter digits only in your edit text.

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(caloriesIn.getText().toString())

Comment: But how do i take that and make it into an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
 int calories = Integer.parseInt(caloriesIn.getText().toString());
 int fat = Integer.parseInt(fatIn.getText().toString());
```

The main problem is in these lines, it will give error is you pass any character here or leave it blank, to solve these add these lines to your code

```
String calIn =  caloriesIn.getText().toString(); //first take input in String for checking
    String fatInStr = fatIn.getText().toString(); //first take input in String for checking

    if (calIn.isEmpty()) {
         Toast.makeText(...);//inform user that calories input field is empty
        return;
    } else if (fatInStr.isEmpty()) {
         Toast.makeText(...);//inform user that fat input field is empty
        return;
    } else if (!calIn.matches("[0-9]+")) {
         Toast.makeText(...);//inform user that calories input field contains invalid data
        return;
    } else if (!fatInStr.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        // Toast.makeText(...);//inform user that fat input field contains invalid data
        return;
    }
    int calories = Integer.parseInt(calIn.trim()); // trim method removes any leading and trailing spaces
    int fat = Integer.parseInt(fatInStr.trim());
```

Now app is safe when text is empty and is not a digit :)