# Skipping frames when setting new image to multiple ImageViews on the same time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to change the image on 15 `ImageViews` on the same time in my Android app with the `setImageResource()` method, but I either get this error message: `I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`. Or the app crashes.

Here is the XML code of how I set up the `ImageViews`:

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
   android:id="@+id/logo1" />
```

And here is how I setup the `ImageViews` and change their image:

```
private ImageView logo1;
private ImageView logo2;
...
private ImageView logo15;

logo1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo1);
logo2...
...
logo15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo15);

logo1.setImageResource(R.drawable.newLogo1);
logo2...
...
logo15.setImageResource(R.drawable.newLogo15);
```

If I were to only change the image for one `ImageView` the app works fine, but when I change 15 at the same time the app crashes..

Answer (score 0):

"Skipped 46 frames!" means some heavy processing is in your application.

Refer this for more info : 
[The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

I recommend using recycler view of images rather than loading all of them at once.