# Application is becoming very slow while retrieving data from server

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-volley, data-retrieval

I'm using the following codes to fetch data from a server using `Volley` library. Without the Internet, the app works fast and smooth when it doesn't retrieve data. But with the Internet turned on, the app becomes slow as it fetches data from the server and displays them in a `ListView`. Is it because of data retrieval? Please help me out on this one.

Following are the codes used:

```
private void  callgetTaskUrlApi() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getTaskUrl,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                arrayList.clear();
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("dataObj");
                    int length=ja.length();

                    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
                        JSONObject temp = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        nameC= temp.getString("name");
                        checkId=temp.getString("clientEid");
                        clientName=temp.getString("client");
                        candidateFatherName=temp.getString("fatherName");
                        clientProcess=temp.getString("otherId");
                        dueDate=temp.getString("deadline");
                        JSONArray jsaDate = temp.getJSONArray("updateDetails");
                        for(int k=0; k<jsaDate.length(); k++){
                            JSONObject jo1 = jsaDate.getJSONObject(k);
                            sentDate = jo1.getString("date");
                        }
                        JSONArray ja1 = temp.getJSONArray("address");
                        for(int j=0; j<ja1.length(); j++){
                            JSONObject jo1 = ja1.getJSONObject(j);
                            landmark=jo1.getString("landmark");
                            district= jo1.getString("district");
                            userAddrss=jo1.getString("full");
                            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                            List<Address> address1=null;
                            List<Address> addresses = null;
                            try {
                                address1 = coder.getFromLocationName(district, 5);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (address1 == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fetching Location,Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                return;
                            }
                            final Address location11 = address1.get(0);
                            location11.getLatitude();
                            location11.getLongitude();
                            if (checkPermission()) {
                                LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                                Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

                                if (location != null) {
                                    latti = location.getLatitude();
                                    longi = location.getLongitude();
                                } else if (location1 != null) {
                                    latti = location1.getLatitude();
                                    longi = location1.getLongitude();
                                } else if (location2 != null) {
                                    latti = location2.getLatitude();
                                    longi = location2.getLongitude();
                                }
                                coder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

                                try {
                                    addresses = coder.getFromLocation(latti, longi, 1);
                                    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                                        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                                         area = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                        String city = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                        String county = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                        String postal_code = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                                        fullAddress=address+","+area+","+city+","+county+","+postal_code;
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            LatLng source = new LatLng(latti, longi);
                            LatLng destination = new LatLng(location11.getLatitude(), location11.getLongitude());
                            double dis= SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(source,destination);
                            dis/=1000;
                            arrayList.add(new DataModel(nameC,userAddrss,landmark,checkId,Math.floor(dis*100)/100,clientName,candidateFatherName,clientProcess,sentDate,dueDate));
                        }
                    }
                    ..
                    ..

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                })
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        return map;
                    }
                };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

`DataholderAdapter.java`

```
public class DataHolderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {    
        private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
        Context mContext;
        static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        // View lookup cache
        private static class ViewHolder {
             TextView txtName;
            TextView txtAddress;
            TextView txtLandmark;
            TextView getDirection;
            TextView shortDistance;
        }

        public DataHolderAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.listview_show, data);
            this.dataSet = data;
            this.mContext=context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) getItem(position);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

            final View result;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_show, parent, false);
                viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                viewHolder.txtAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
                viewHolder.txtLandmark = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Landmark);
                viewHolder.getDirection=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDirections);
                viewHolder.shortDistance=convertView.findViewById(R.id.shortestDistance);
                progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                viewHolder.getDirection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        progressDialog.setMessage("Opening maps...");
                        progressDialog.show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("destination",viewHolder.txtAddress.getText().toString());
                        i.putExtra("DataHolder","dataholder");
                        getContext().startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                result=convertView;
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                result=convertView;
            }
            viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getName());
            viewHolder.txtAddress.setText(dataModel.getAddress());
            viewHolder.txtLandmark.setText(Html.fromHtml("<strong>Landmark: </strong>"+dataModel.getLandmark()));
                viewHolder.shortDistance.setText(dataModel.getShortDistance() + " kms");
                //viewHolder.shortDistance.setBackgroundResource(R.attr.bgHighlight);
             return convertView;
       }
    }
```

Message I received:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 167 frames!  The application may be doing 
too much work on its main thread.
D/Dialog: mIsSamsungBasicInteraction = false
```

Comment: Why people are downvoting the question.I provided all the details

Comment: Refer this one ->> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Geocoder.getFromLocationName` is blocking your UI thread. From documentation

> The query will block and returned values will be obtained by means of a network lookup. The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or correct. It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread.

For more info visit this [url](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%2520int))

Comment: Thank you so much bro.I commented those lines and tried running the app.Now the app is running smooth.But i need to implement the getFromLocatioName in another thread.I will revert to you if I have any further problem

Comment: Bro,i have put the callTaskGetUrl method in AsyncTask do in background method.But still the app is slow.Please help

Comment: How do you detect the app is slow? AsyncTask exectutes tasks synchronously i.e executes one task and then the next one. It never executes tasks parallelly.

Comment: Can you help me.I got one problem