# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

How come I have this message in my Flutter android app? I try with the counter app which is the first app made by flutter team, it shows this message too. Does it need to be fixed?  How do we fix it?

```dart
I/Choreographer( 5455): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295725/7098524

Comment: And then read: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#what-is-the-equivalent-of-runonuithread-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of factors that may cause frame skipping. It may be dependent on some of these items:

- The size of the widget tree to be displayed on the screen.
- Speed of the CPU that does computational work, i.e. parsing JSONs at startup.
- The speed of the network connection in case of needing some necessary data before the app starts up.
- If you're using an emulator or a physical device.

You may also want to consider testing the app on a physical device and see if similar frame skipping occurs. If not, and if you're not doing anything unnecessary on the screen, then this can be safely ignored.