# How to use chrome custom tabs in flutter

Tags: android, google-chrome, flutter, dart

I wanted to use chrome custom tabs in flutter. I know there is a package for that(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs), but on using that package, when I run the app, it shows error messages like,

Note: /home/jatin/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_custom_tabs-0.6.0/android/src/main/java/com/github/droibit/flutter/plugins/customtabs/internal/Launcher.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Skipped 183 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread,

So, is there any other way to use chrome custom tabs more efficiently in flutter? If not, then how can we add custom tabs using native code (only in android) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without codes its not really easy to say if there is something wrong with the way you wrote is causing the problem.
But
The first part of your error message says that you are using a library (custom tabs in your case) which is using a deprecated library. This in itself is not a big problem.

However the second part of the error says that the problem (maybe) is the work on your main thread is becoming too heavy for your emulator to handle hence it is showing this error. Please look into the link for explanation. Hope this helps.

[See here for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this popular package- [in_appwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview#chromesafaribrowser-class). It has several classess so you can easy implement `webview`, `chrome_custom_tab`, even `in app browser`.