# App is not loading the Views a second time if receiving a message from MessagingCenter and updating the UI afterwards

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin

I am sending an intent I am receiving through a `BroadcastReceiver` to multiple Views in my shared-project. The `DisplayResult`-method implements the `MessagingCenter.Send`.

```
public class MyBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver
{
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.Action;
            if (action.Equals(MainActivity.Instance.Resources.GetString(intentString)))
            {
                
                //Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MainActivity.Instance.DisplayResult(intent)); 
                //Task.Run(() => MainActivity.Instance.DisplayResult(intent));
                //MainActivity.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() => MainActivity.Instance.DisplayResult(intent));
            }
        }
}
```

If a message is received I want to update my Views e.g. like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, Model>(this, "HI", (sender, arg) =>
                {   
                    
                        var dt = DateTime.Now;
                        _logger.Debug($"Task started: {dt}");
                        
                        ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
                        ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
                        
                        Task.Run(async () =>
                        {                            
                            await SomeTask();                          
                        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        _logger.Debug($"Task finished: {DateTime.Now - dt}");
                        
                        ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                        ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
                        
                    }
                });
```

The issue is if I use the approach with `Task.Run(...)` my Views are only showing up once **but** the `ActivityIndicator` is running. That means if I close a View and go back to the MainPage and navigate to another or the same View again it only shows a white screen.

If I use either `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(...)` or `RunOnUiThread(...)` I get the [skipped frames error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread). And my app is frozen until every Task within the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` in my Views is finished. The `ActivityIndicator` is **Not** showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try with using `async` method to invoke these method as follow:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PageMain, string>(this, "HI", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    var dt = DateTime.Now;
    _logger.Debug($"Task started: {dt}");

    ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

    await SomeTask();

    _logger.Debug($"Task finished: {DateTime.Now - dt}");

    ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
    ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
});
```