# Android doing too much work on its main thread when rendering complex UI on Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-constraintlayout

I have a child fragment (2nd/3rd node) that consists of a complex UI.

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>
 - ScrollView
    - ConstraintLayout
       - 1 ImageView
       - 18 TextView
       - 13 TextInputLayout each has it's own TextInputEditText
       - 1 RecyclerView
 - Guideline
 - 5 Buttons
</ConstraintLayout>
```

1. Fragment opens slowly
2. It gives the warning `Android doing too much work on its main thread` and skipping many frames.
3. Each field is getting observed from the ViewModel `ObservableField` values. (Not setting the values also cause the same warning)

Comment: 18 TextView  and 13 TextInputLayout i would say u might wanna rethink your UX for this . Anyway Are there any view which are Conditionally Visible ? If yes You can use ViewStub for those Views  . Here is a thread on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Comment: `ViewStub` sounds good, this comes to a condition of which would be a good option as per performance? 
1. Using multiple `ViewStub` by dividing 18 TextView and 1 TextInputLayout into multiple sub-groups
2. Using a RecyclerView