# Empty Activity with jetpack compose: Skipped 37 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Iam always having this message:

> Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
> main thread.

Even when I´m starting a new application with an empty compose Activity.
Is there any solution can help ? Thanks in advanced!

I tried to update my android studio, but I got the same issue

Comment: Are you using the emulator? Have you tried testing it in a real device?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Comment: If using a debug build, then the extra log output and transfer of the log output to Android Studio can slow things down enough to cause skipped frames.

Comment: @fernandospr I'm having this issue for both real device and in the emulator

Comment: @CodePoet Thanks but I saw this link before, the thing is the even for a new project I'm having this issue, I cannot identify any node that in this case