# Receive response from socket cases crash

Tags: java, sockets

Im trying to receive response from a socket ( android studio environment). This response have more than one line . When receiving finished app get crashes . This is the code im using:

```
        try {
    
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    
            StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    
            int bytesRead;
    
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    
                String response = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    
                responseBuilder.append(response);
    
            }
    
            String receivedResponse = responseBuilder.toString();
    
            Log.d("RawSocket", "Received response: " + receivedResponse);
    
        } catch (IOException e) {
    
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

down here is stack trace:

```
    D/RawSocket: Received response:  19
    2023/10/30 62:38 V=  1 TAG  18
    2023/10/30 62:29 V=  1 TAG  17
    2023/10/30 62:28 V=  1 TAG  16
    2023/10/30 42:05 V=  1 TAG  15
    2023/10/30 42:04 V=  1 TAG  14
    2023/10/30 41:53 V=  1 TAG  13
    2023/10/30 52:51 V=  1 TAG  12
    2023/10/30 52:50 V=  1 TAG  11
    2023/10/28 49:35 V=  1 TAG  10
    2023/10/28 49:11 V=  1 TAG   9
    2023/10/28 49:10 V=  1 TAG   8
    2023/10/28 48:19 V=  1 TAG   7
    2023/10/28 47:43 V=  1 TAG   6
    2023/10/28 47:43 V=  1 TAG   5
    2023/10/28 47:42 V=  1 TAG   4
    2023/10/28 46:57 V=  1 TAG   3
    2023/10/28 46:53 V=  1 TAG   2
    2023/10/28 46:53 V=  1 TAG   1
    2023/10/28 46:53 V=  1 TAG 
    W/Looper: PerfMonitor longMsg : seq=1867 plan=12:49:21.881 late=5ms wall=10525ms running=28ms runnable=4ms h=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler c=android.view.View$PerformClick procState=-1
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 632 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    W/Looper: PerfMonitor doFrame : time=37ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=10535ms procState=-1 historyMsgCount=1
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=10583ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=2176098, IntendedVsync=43296186865024, Vsync=43306720197936, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=43306721982801, AnimationStart=43306722573374, PerformTraversalsStart=43306722593322, DrawStart=43306753145197, FrameDeadline=43296220198356, FrameInterval=43306721523478, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=43306756274364, SyncStart=43306756526499, IssueDrawCommandsStart=43306757182958, SwapBuffers=43306766297333, FrameCompleted=43306770417437, DequeueBufferDuration=86302, QueueBufferDuration=2839687, GpuCompleted=43306770417437, SwapBuffersCompleted=43306770417437, DisplayPresentTime=514951064320, 
    I/libc: Requested dump for tid 6911 (.TAGSAZAN.batag)
    D/DecorView[]: onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
```

What can i do to prevent app from crashing?

I tried above code and received all responses but when responses finished, app crashed.

Comment: No idea what the error is or what caused the crash. Post a stack trace

Comment: i added stack trace  to the main question

Comment: it looks like you maybe doing some really processing intensive task on your main thread. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126690/16034206

Comment: Your stacktrace does not contain the relevant part where the app "crashed".