# Right Track with Log Message

Tags: android, eclipse, logging

I just wanna know if I am on the right track. Well I'm used to `Netbeans` for `java` but since `Eclipse` is best for android I decided using `Eclipse`. Whenever I run my App on Eclipse and check The Log Message I found a lot of Warnings, although It worked well on both emulators and device. But I hope this doesn't have nothing to do with the effectiveness of the app latter in the future. Also sometimes my `Eclipse` misbehave with some unnecessary errors (without errors in the code)which correct itself when closed and restarted again (Is this a bug, I'm using the latest `Eclipse`). I will appreciate your comments.

Below are some of the Log Message:

```
06-03 12:41:04.603: W/Trace(3934): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.613: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.683: W/Trace(3934): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.713: W/Trace(3934): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.713: W/Trace(3934): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.884: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.906: W/Trace(3934): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.906: W/Trace(3934): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.953: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:04.973: I/Choreographer(3395): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-03 12:41:05.133: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:05.133: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:05.143: I/Choreographer(3395): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-03 12:41:05.553: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:05.594: I/Choreographer(3395): Skipped 612 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-03 12:41:05.633: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:05.633: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:05.763: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:05.793: W/Trace(3395): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 12:41:05.793: W/SoundPool(3395):   sample 0 not READY
06-03 12:41:05.854: D/PhoneStatusBar(3934): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK HOME recent* CLOCK search >
06-03 12:41:05.883: W/Trace(3511): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Sequence to the warning message received from `LogCat` I really like to know if its normal. because seriously I don't have much work done on my main thread. And any Activity with database query are all executed in
 `Thread thread = new Thread(Runable);
thread.start()`. Please I need clarification since I get this same warning message event in empty activity (I mean Activity with no job). Please I need serious help here because I don't want to be doing the wrong thing thinking I'm doing the write thing

Comment: Some information about the log items you see here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858680/logcat-says-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread-and

regarding the errors in code, try to hit F5 or refresh then eclipse will check again the code, and the warning / errors should be gone. If this doesn't help make sure the file is saved. Also an option is to enable build automatically for project

Answer (score 0):

This warning tells you, that you are doing too much work on the UI Thread. That is the main thread. This will surely cause problems on devices running low on battery, power or poor hardware. You should optimize your code and perform heavy tasks in A separate thread. For which you should consider AsyncTask - a class available in android for multi-threading.

Comment: So its a treat seeing warnings in long. But is it possible to eliminate it totally.